# How to turn on or off DND using dart in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, do-not-disturb

I want to turn on and off **do not disturb mode** in android using flutter.

My Question is :
"Is there any way to achieve it without writing native code (i.e. any package or direct dart code)"

Comment: you must write native code

Comment: did you succeed at this?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a feature, Android will not allow apps to disable something the user has set, especially since this can annoy people **badly**. By native, you mean Kotlin/ Java/ Android code. I see lots of developers using native to mean anything below them. In Android, we use native to mean C/ C++/ actual native code. Maybe the C++ developers will call assembly native, IDK.

Comment: any update on this question?

Comment: You can use [flutter_dnd](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dnd) package. Here is the [medium blog](https://sathish76.medium.com/control-dnd-settings-in-flutter-e53481cb6ec5) for this package